# How to add an access method in Postgres 9.4

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.4

After PostgreSQL v9.6, there's a `CREATE ACCESS METHOD` statement to introduce a new index method, but how could i create a new access method in PostgreSQL v9.4 and before?

Comment: Short of hacking the source code, I don't think there is a way to do that. But 9.4 is no longer supported anyway. You should upgrade to a current version anyway as soon as possible. But what is the **real** problem you are trying to solve here? I very much doubt that it can be solved by adding an index access method.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to modify the PostgreSQL source code, which is something that seems not worth the effort for an old, unsupported release.

Upgrade!